# Marrying my Brazilian Fiance / Fiance visa

Tags: visas, uk, weddings

I am due to marry my fiancé in October 2018 and we fully understand that he cannot come to the UK for longer than 6 months prior to the wedding on a fiancé visa. We both currently live in Australia and plan to spend time in Brazil and travel to Europe until he can enter the UK.

However he does need to come to the UK to register for the marriage. So can he come as a tourist and then change to a fiancé visa? Or does he need to leave the UK and apply for a fiancé visa outside of the UK?

Comment: This is not really a travel question, and I think you should ask to local authority, where you give the paper for the marriage. They should know better all such (frequent) special cases. Laws change quickly, so. As alternative, you can marry her in Brazil, and than give the official paper to consulate (to validate marriage).

Comment: `tourist and then change to a fiancé visa` That will have some interesting repercussions if the border agent suspects something.

Comment: I would recommend not to marry on a tourist visa. it may pose problems if he wants to reside on the UK in the future. Not sure though.

Comment: Is your fiancé a UK citizen or are you? Are you planning to get married in the UK? If your question is about eventual settlement in the UK, it belongs on expatriates.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear because you live in Australia, so it's unclear why the UK has any relevance whatsoever.  Are you planning to get married there?  Are you planning to settle there after the marriage or to return to Australia?

Comment: As an aside, if you're planning to marry in the UK without settling there, then you should know about the [marriage visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa).